# using mapper class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

Hi I'm using clean architecture in my project but I'm stuck with mapping my data class that contains a list how can I solve it ?

My mapper class in data module :

```
 fun toMapper(data: Data): DataModel {

    return DataModel(
        data.title ?: ""

    )
}
```

My data class in data module :

```
data class Data(

@SerializedName("title")
var title: String? = null,
@SerializedName("movie")
var movie: List<Movie>? = null
```

)

My data class in domain module :

```
var title: String?,
var movieModel: List<MovieModel>?
```

Comment: erm... what's the problem? What are `MovieModel` and `Movie`?

Comment: movie class is my entity in data module and movie model is my data class in domain module I want to pass the parameter list<movie> to mapper class but I don't know how

Comment: Can you show us the code of those 2 classes and explain what do you mean by mapper class? You've shown a function (toMapper) which returns a `DataModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly DataModel has these two parameters?

```
var title: String?,
var movieModel: List<MovieModel>?
```

In that case I assume you want to convert List to List

For doing that you can just use the .map function on the List and then get the MovieModel object for each Movie

So

```
 fun toMapper(data: Data): DataModel {

    return DataModel(
        data.title ?: "",
        data.movie?.map(//IMPLEMENT MAPPING MOVIE-> MOVIEMODEL HERE)

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note- You have to create mapper for each and every model separately.**

```
fun toMapper(data: Data): DataModel {

    return DataModel(
        data.title ?: "",
        data.movie?.map(mapperToMovieModel(it))
    )
}
```

> Create a *mapper function* for **MovieModel**.

**Considering *Movie* Class to be simple and *MovieModel* is same too-**

```
class Movie{

 val movieName:String

}
```

> Function to map **Movie** to **MovieModel**

```
fun mapperToMovieModel(movie: Movie): MovieModel {

    return MovieModel(
        movie.movieName ?: "",
    )
}
```